# Division of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that $9|n$ if and only if $9$ divides the sum of the digits of $n$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Try inducting on the number of digits of the natural number

Answer (score -1):

Hint : $10^n\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 9\ )$ for all $n\ge 0$.